# How to resize a JPanel to fit a JFrame in "docknorth" with no interference to remaining JPanels

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, miglayout

I am doing a little test of a demo Swing GUI. In this demo, the `JFrame` is composed of 3 "master" `JPanel`s. If you will, the first (`jp1`) is composed of `JLabel`s, and the other two are composed of several other `JPanel`s. I am using MigLayout.

Here is my sample code:

```
    // All the jPanels  
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setLayout(new MigLayout());
    JPanel jp1 = new JPanel();
    jp1.setLayout(new MigLayout());
    jp1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY, 1));
    JPanel jp2 = new JPanel();
    jp2.setLayout(new MigLayout());
    jp2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY, 1));
    JPanel jp3 = new JPanel();
    jp3.setLayout(new MigLayout());
    jp3.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY, 1));
    JPanel jp4 = new JPanel();
    jp4.setLayout(new MigLayout());
    jp4.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY, 1));
    JPanel jp5 = new JPanel();
    jp5.setLayout(new MigLayout());
    jp5.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY, 1));
    JPanel jp6 = new JPanel();
    jp6.setLayout(new MigLayout());
    jp6.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY, 1));
    JPanel jp7 = new JPanel();
    jp7.setLayout(new MigLayout());
    jp7.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY, 1));

    JPanel bigPanel1 = new JPanel();
    bigPanel1.setLayout(new MigLayout());
    bigPanel1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY, 1));

    JPanel bigPanel2 = new JPanel();
    bigPanel2.setLayout(new MigLayout());
    bigPanel2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY, 1));
    //All the labels to be added to JPanel jp1
    JLabel label1 = new JLabel();
    label1.setText("LABEL1");
    JLabel label2 = new JLabel();
    label2.setText("LABEL2");
    JLabel label3 = new JLabel();
    label3.setText("LABEL3");
    JLabel label4 = new JLabel();
    label4.setText("LABEL4");
    jp1.add(label1);
    jp1.add(label2);
    jp1.add(label3);
    jp1.add(label4,"wrap");
    bigPanel1.add(jp2);
    bigPanel1.add(jp6);
    bigPanel1.add(jp3,"grow,wrap");
    bigPanel2.add(jp4);
    bigPanel2.add(jp7);
    bigPanel2.add(jp5,"grow,wrap");
    frame.getContentPane().add(jp1,"dock north, wrap");
    frame.getContentPane().add(bigPanel1,"span,grow,wrap");
    frame.getContentPane().add(bigPanel2,"span,grow,wrap");
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Which results in this output:[GUI OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wx0SJ.png)

What I want to achieve is being able to add labels into the 1st `JPanel` (`jp1`) without messing with the remainder `JPanel`s width. 
Additionally, I want to make the several `JPanel`s inside a `bigPanel` to occupy its full width, as well as in `jp2`,`jp6` and `jp3` to fill `bigPanel1`.

How should I do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: By your screen shot it seems all can be one with default `JPanel` Layout - `FlowLayout`. why even bother with extra libs when Java has it all bundled and more help is available?... Or Im just a 3rd party `LayoutManager` hater :P

Comment: By all means if that's what it takes. So, in a FlowLayout scenario, how should configure my demo?

Comment: Using Mig is not really a requirement. I'm using it as I thought it would be better. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never used `MigLayout`, and personally dont see the reason if it can be done using default java `LayoutManager`.

Okay so I used a combination `FlowLayout` and [`GridBagLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) to achieve this, along with  `gc.fill=GridBagConstraints.NONE` and `gc.anchor=GridBagConstraints.WEST` for those panels which we dont want to fill the *contentpane* width, also updated as per your comment to stop the `JPanel`/`JFrame` from growing larger than the given max width when more `JLabel`s are added this was done using a `JScrollPane`:

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class Test {

    public Test() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        final JPanel labelPanel = new JPanel();
        labelPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black));
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            labelPanel.add(new JLabel("Label" + (i + 1)));
        }

        final int maxWidth = 200;
        final JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(labelPanel) {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                //we set the height by checking if we exceeed the wanted ith thus a scrollbar will appear an we must incoprate that or labels wont be shpwn nicely
                return new Dimension(maxWidth, labelPanel.getPreferredSize().width < maxWidth ? (labelPanel.getPreferredSize().height + 5) : ((labelPanel.getPreferredSize().height + getHorizontalScrollBar().getPreferredSize().height) + 5));
            }
        };

        JPanel otherPanel = new JPanel();
        otherPanel.add(new JLabel("label"));
        otherPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black));

        JPanel otherPanel2 = new JPanel();
        otherPanel2.add(new JLabel("label 1"));
        otherPanel2.add(new JLabel("label 2"));
        otherPanel2.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black));

        GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();

        gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gc.weightx = 1.0;
        gc.weighty = 1.0;
        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 0;
        frame.add(jsp, gc);

        gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gc.gridy = 1;
        frame.add(otherPanel, gc);
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gc.gridy = 2;
        frame.add(otherPanel2, gc);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.revalidate();
        frame.repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Create Swing components on EDT
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This actually allows adding labels to the `labelPanel` without messing with the other JPanels width. Is there any way to make the the `labelPanel` fit a certain size, like fullscreen size and stop growing in width making upcoming labels to stretch?

Comment: I feel so stupid now. Simply add a JScrollPane and it does the trick even more nicely. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I have use `BorderLayout` and `FlowLayout` to manage the layouts. The frame has two `JPanel's` and one `JPanel` in it has two more `JPanel's`. All the internal panels use `FlowLayout` to align the `JLabels`. To arrange these panels on the `JFrame` I have used `BorderLayout`.

[image: Layout Manager]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class LayoutTest {

    public LayoutTest() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        JPanel motherPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

        motherPanel.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        motherPanel.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel topUpperPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        JPanel topBottomPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

        topUpperPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        topBottomPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        bottomPanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));

        topPanel.add(topUpperPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        topPanel.add(topBottomPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            JLabel label = new JLabel("Label-" + String.valueOf(i));
            label.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
            topUpperPanel.add(label);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            JLabel label = new JLabel("Label-" + String.valueOf(i));
            label.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
            topBottomPanel.add(label);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            JLabel label = new JLabel("Label-" + String.valueOf(i));
            label.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
            bottomPanel.add(label);
        }

        frame.add(motherPanel);
        frame.setTitle("Layout Manager");
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new LayoutTest();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**P.S:** I would suggest you to separate the panels such that there will be "whithout no interference with remaining JPanels."

Comment: nice and uses my initial FlowLayout idea though OP had border on the JPanel and not JLabel hence OP question on how to make JPanel not fill the width

Comment: @DavidKroukamp Is it that OP want only Border up to the size of the _JLabel_ or Border for the entire panel of each row?

Comment: The entire panel as far as I understand

Comment: @Che Thanks a lot for your answer. Both answers were very helpful.